# How to enable the "This site is trying to open this application" prompt on websites in Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, browser

[The same question but for Edge.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/how-to-enable-a-site-ask-this-site-is-trying-to/5b511f02-2ae7-445f-b04c-fcdd5af2f0aa)

So one time I have clicked "Always allow this site to open application" but I want the website to ask about it again.

In Chrome there is no `Application Links` like in Edge. I tried to delete all cookies but it still runs the app without asking.

So how do I enable it again?

Comment: Do you have `Insecure origins treated as secure` enabled or disabled under chrome://flags/?